# Simple Regular Expression to Replace All But

Tags: javascript, regex

Having a brainfreeze

I have the following string:  "pvtVal row1 col3 this is a test"

How do I get rid of anything that is not pvtVal row\d+ or col\d+

so for example:

```
 var test="pvtVal row1 col3 this is a test".replace(/(^(pvtVal |row\d+ |col\d+ ))/g, '');
```

Unfortunately it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: You might use `match` and `join` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing, you can do this using [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var teststr = 'pvtVal row1 col3 this is a test',
    matches = teststr.match(/(?:pvtVal|row\d+|col\d+)/g),
    results = matches.join(' ');

console.log(results); // => "pvtVal row1 col3"
```

Comment: Jah that's better than mine. Stuck in one thinking mode today, everything looks like a nail to my hammer. :) +1